# Pymysql UPDATE with %s rises unknown error

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update, pymysql

I try to update a line in my sql database with pymysql. To make the whole thing more pythonic I define the variables and position to update with `%s`.
This has worked for one variable, however the other is rising an error i don't understand.
This is my code:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    #sql = "update tf_data set doi=\'"+str(DOI)+"\' where tf_data_id="+str(tf_data_id)+";"
    sql = "update tf_data set doi=%(DOI)s where tf_data_id=%(data_id)s"
    DOI=DOI
    data_id = str(tf_data_id)
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

Connection was defined at the beginning of the script and has already worked.
The variables are:

```
DOI= '10.1371/journal.pone.0151666'
```

and `tf_data_id = 1`
if I execute, what I think the command should do in mysql directly it workes:

```
update tf_data set doi='10.1371/journal.pone.0151666' where tf_data_id='1';
```

Can someone please tell me, what the problem in this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just

```
sql = "update tf_data set doi='%s' where tf_data_id='%s'" % (str(DOI), str(tf_data_id))
```

or you could use `format()` method

```
sql = "update tf_data set doi='{DOI}' where tf_data_id='{data_id}'".format(DOI=DOI, data_id= tf_data_id)
```

Comment: the first method gave another error, the ´format()´ method did the job, thanks!

Comment: what is the difference between these ways of updating with pymsql?

Comment: @MaxS Both methods should provide same results. Could you try first method once more?

Comment: @MaxS First version of code was without quotes around `%s`. Probably, this cause problem.

Comment: But what happens if for example your DOI is None?